# Angular js Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller xxxx, required by directive yyyy, can't be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I already multiple topics on stackoverflow about this error but I always don't understand the problem in my context.

**I have this template:**

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar"
     data-toggle="tooltip"
     title="Parts offertes : {{ '{{ gift.gived_parts}}' }} / {{ '{{ gift.number_of_parts }}' }}"
     data-bar="gived"
     >
    <span ng-class="{true:'op7', false:''}[gift.percent_done > 0 && gift.percent_done < 20]">
        {{ '{{ gift.gived_parts}}' }}
    </span>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animate active op7"
     data-toggle="tooltip" 
     title="Parts réservées&nbsp;:&nbsp;{{ '{{ gift.total_reserved}}' }}&nbsp;/&nbsp;{{ '{{ gift.number_of_parts }}' }}"
     data-bar="reserved">
</div>
```

**For this directive:**

```
app.directive('progressBarD', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: rootUrl + '/directive/progressBar',
    scope: {
        gift: '=gift'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
        var bars = $elem.find(".progress-bar");
        bars.each(function() {
            var bar = $(this);
            var percent = (bar.context.dataset.bar === "gived")
                ? $scope.gift.percent_done
                : $scope.gift.percent_reserved;

            if (($().appear) && isMobileDevice === false && (bars.hasClass("no-anim") === false) ) {
                bar.appear(function () {
                    bar.addClass("progress-bar-animate").css("width", percent + "%");
                }, {accY: -150} );
            } else {
                bar.css("width", percent + "%");
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

**And here is the call of the directive:**

```
<progress-bar-d gift="gift"></progress-bar-d>
```

During the execution, I obtain this error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'progress', required by directive 'bar', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/ctreq?p0=progress&p1=bar
at angular.js:63
at getControllers (angular.js:7583)
at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7772)
at angular.js:7998
at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
at angular.js:13264
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1468)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
```

On the screen, the link function look to work, but at the end, the    inside the first   desapear when  gift.percent_done is different of 0.

Could you explain me why I have this angular error ? Do the deletion of the span is the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.

In the anguluar directive I change bar.context.dataset.bar and it work.
I don't know why that was not well interpreted but now it work.